# Why didn't Samir Wassan say J.C. Wheeler's name during his routine?

Tags: the-twilight-zone, the-twilight-zone-2019

In the Twilight Zone episode [The Comedian](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9089912/), Wassan gets some advice from J.C Wheeler and uses it in his stand up act.

If he opens up about himself, the audience will be more receptive. He does so and realizes that the people he mentions in his act begin to disappear from the timeline.

In the end he says his own name and disappears from existence.

Why didn't he say J.C Wheeler's name? Everyone he made disappear would return because J.C Wheeler would never have given him the advice.

Comment: Wouldn't have been much of a story if it never happened, would it?

Comment: @ZeissIkon - I don't mean at the beginning, but at the end, instead of saying his own name, he could have said JC Wheeler's name.

Comment: Well that would be a paradox. If J.C. never gave Samir the advice, J.C's name wouldn't get said, so he would give him the advice...

Comment: @MattEllen - I don't think it's a paradox, he says J.C Wheeler's name on stage, JCW gets erased from the timeline. JCW never gives him the advice about opening up on stage, so he remains a low level comedian and the people around him don't disappear.

Comment: If Samir never gets the advice, how does JCW get erased from the timeline?

Comment: It's not time travel, at the beginning JCW gives him the advice, and people start disappearing. He mentions the comedian who caused the car wreck, so he disappears, and the bus stop is never destoryed. If he mentioned JCW name, JCW would disappear, the people Wassan made disappear would return, but he would reamin a low level comedian (because he never opened up on stage or given that he seems to remember the people that disappear, he would stop taking JCW advice).

Comment: It is information time travel. If people come back after an event is undone, then undoing JCW will make JCW come back, no?

Comment: @MattEllen - Time travel logic gives me a headache. I don't think JCW would come back, but the people he made disappear after taking the advice would. Unless JCW is unaffected by the timeline changes and is the only character that nobody can make disappear.

Comment: @MattEllen - By your logic, Wassan would never disappear, and the people he made disappear would come back, which includes himself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92257/discussion-between-matt-ellen-and-nsonline).

Comment: @MattEllen - Sorry about the chat request. I left the question for a while hoping for an official answer. I read your comment and I have to agree. I guess your comment is the answer :).

Comment: For the record, I agree with @MattEllen: it would result in a paradox. If mentioning JCW removes JCW and undoes everything his advice did, it would also remove JCW's own removal.